# Transpose RDD[Vector] to change records to attributes for an csv of size 500.000 x 50

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, transpose

I would like to read a csv file and transpose it to measure correlation between attributes. But when I transpose it I get below error:

> not enough arguments for method transpose: (implicit asTraversable:
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector =>
>   scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])Seq[Seq[B]]. Unspecified value
>   parameter asTraversable.

Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

```
val file = "/data.csv"   
val data = sc.textFile(file).map(line => Vectors.dense(line.split (",").map(_.toDouble).distinct))
val transposedData = sc.parallelize(data.collect.toSeq.transpose)
val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(transposedData, "pearson")
println(correlMatrix.toString)
```

Comment: data is already a rdd . why are you collecting it and again converting to rdd? and why are you using transpose for ? clarify

Comment: So each line(vector) is a record and holds attributes. I want to find correlation between those 50 attributes. I thought if I send my RDD as it is into correlMatrix, it would calculate the correlation between records rather than attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > not enough arguments for method transpose: (implicit asTraversable: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])Seq[Seq[B]]. Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.

`data` RDD is a collection of `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` *i.e. collection of objects*. But *transpose would require collection of collection*.

`data.collect.toSeq` simply gives you `Seq[Vector]` which cannot be transposed.

The following code should work for you

```
val data = sc.textFile(file).map(line => line.split (",").map(_.toDouble))
val untransposedData = data.map(Vectors.dense(_))
val transposedData = sc.parallelize(data.collect.toSeq.transpose).map(x => Vectors.dense(x.toArray))
val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(transposedData, "pearson")
println(correlMatrix.toString)
```

**Note:** *`distinct` is removed as it would make the two dimentional matrix to be uneven which would lead to another issue.*